# Convert laravel password to crypt encryption

Tags: laravel, nginx, passwords, crypt

I need my users to use their laravel's account password in another nginx server (for http authentication) which uses crypt encription. How can I do this conversion? Is that even possible?

Comment: No you can't do this, because Laravel stores only hashed passwords and one cannot retrieve the original password from a hash.

Answer (score 2):

Encrypting passwords is bad practice since it's reversible. Always store them in an irreversible format, e.g. hashes.

If you still want to encrypt the passwords, you should [write a custom user provider](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet).